# How can I spread requests across multiple REST servers equally

Tags: rest, iis, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

We have an ASP.NET WebAPI2 REST server. Requests to it are async where a request is submitted and returns a guid. And then the caller polls for the status on that guid. We have customers that will feed over 1,000 requests and then continue to feed up and poll. And it can be 15 minutes until the last of the 1,000 is complete.

With a single server this works fine. Each request we create a Task in our app and IIS then handles processing them within its thread pool.

But load balancing is a problem. Handing 500 requests each to two servers is not necessarily equal. Once could complete in 2 minutes and the other take 13 minutes. Asking each how many pending jobs won't work because a job can be under 1 second or over 10 minutes.

Logically the only thing I can think of is there's an intermediate store of requests. Then when a server has an available thread, it grabs the next request, processes it, and then saves it off.

Is this the best approach here?

And if so, does IIS have a way of signaling my app when it has an available thread from its pool?

Comment: which load balancing algorithm you are using?

Comment: @JalpaPanchal This is for a commercial product so our customers will each decide how to load balance.